# Java OOP design: what patterns can be used to design a hierarchy in which tasks/methods can be delegated between different instances of objects?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, delegation

For example, if I have a person class, but each instance of a person can have 0 or more position or job - which have specific abilities and responsibilities - that he/she can switch between at will.

Comment: You'll be much better off asking a much more specific question that can be responded to with a specific answer. Also, your question is not clear.

Comment: This description makes me think of many patterns.  Strategy, Observer, Visitor, Command ... for one thing can a person hold many positions at the same time?  Do we want to be able to say, "Do all your jobs".

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html). Basically, the strategy would be their job, but I would probably make a `Worker` or `Employee` class; not all `Person`s are workers.

If a `Person` encapsulates the notion of applying a strategy to accomplish their tasks or responsibilities they can switch tasks or responsibilities on the fly (runtime).